# Add rows and fill data automatically from worksheet A to Worksheet B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hope you all are doing well.

I have two excel worksheets A and B. A is the source and B is the destination. If I make any changes in A it updates B as well. However if I insert a new row anywhere in A it wont update it.
What I have done now is to copy the formula on the additional rows in the end of worksheet A but it shows all 0s in worksheet B which doesn't looks much pretty. I want to find a solution where if I insert any row anywhere in worksheet A, it must get updated in worksheet B as well.

Below is the formula that I have used.

=IFERROR('WorksheetA'!B3,'WorksheetB'!B4)

Here it copies the contents of worksheet A to B and incase a row is removed in A, then instead of giving a reference error, it will update it with the new row.

I can delete a row in A but cannot add and automatically update in B.
Any help is much appreciated.

PS: I am using office 16.

Comment: Using table and inserting row to table may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Then I think you may need to build an add-in, you could consider using Office JS.  here is [an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial#create-your-add-in-project) for create an add-in.
when you build your add-in, you would need to listen to [`onChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#onChanged) for worksheet A, you can have logic to handle the following change type `RowDeleted`、`RowInserted`， and then do the same thing for the worksheet B.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Raymond Lu. I will give it a go.

Comment: Hi Raymond 
I installed nodeJs and Git but when I run the command "npm install -g yo generator-office", it doesn't work. Any ideas what might have gone wrong

Comment: Just realised I was on a protected network and thus the npm command wasn't working